# HTTPS redirect for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file. I am using the `Real Simple SSL` plugin. On my site HTTP is not being redirected to HTTPS. Not really sure what could be the problem.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from xx.xx.xx.xx
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/wp-admin/ [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is a screenshot of the Admin portal of the `Real Simple SSL` settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this rules in your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do I add this or edit what I posted in the question?

Comment: Replace your existing